# Probabilistic Automata / Finite state machines in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, finite-automata, state-machine

Does anyone know of any good resources for probabilistic finite state machines / automata in Clojure? I know of https://github.com/ztellman/automat and https://github.com/cdorrat/reduce-fsm (but I do not think they do what I want).

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_automaton

My problem is fairly simply (I think): I have multiple states, and transition between them is singular i.e. for now it is just a simple fixed distribution. I am still trying to gain clarity as to if this is really an FSM problem.

An almost identical example to my problem:

Suppose I have these states: `Q = {rain,snow,hail,fog,sun}`

Each of these has an associated probability of transitioning into a particular state, i.e. a transition function `D = [0.1 0.1 0.6 0.1 0.1]`. This is not quite an HMM since I do not have any observations, I would just like to simulate the state dynamics i.e. say sample the FSM for maybe 100 time steps: `simulation = {rain,snow,hail,hail,sun,sun,sun,sun,sun,sun,...}`. The state transition table looks something like this:

```
     rain,snow,hail,fog,sun
rain 1   ,1   ,0   ,1  ,1  
snow 1   ,1   ,0   ,1  ,0
hail 0   ,1   ,0   ,0  ,1
fog  1   ,1   ,0   ,0  ,1
sun  0   ,1   ,0   ,1  ,1
```

where `1` is a valid transition and `0` is not. Confusingly I have both a state transition table of valid transitions and a transition probability. Now I am aware that having both is a bit nonsensical (the probabilities are just approximations to the true thing, and the transition table just rounds, in the real problem, to zero).

I suppose I am wondering, where does this fall in the great FSM world (complete novice here). Please feel free to disregard either the transition function or the transition table, whichever makes more sense in FSM world. That being said my problem is of the nature that my system dwells in one state almost all the time - this I do not know how to model without `D` but I also do happen to know what valid state transitions are (which granted could just be built into the state transition function).

Comment: Your example `simulation` appears to be at odds with the rest of your question. It should be a series of *probability distributions* over the states rather than a series of definite states, no? Also, do you have any states that are accepting/final or are you only interested in how the state evolves over time?

Comment: Yeah I thought it might not be entirely clear.. Ok, suppose we disregard `D` and I only have the state transition table. If it is a probability distribution over states then we get the HMM, which, for reasons, I am trying to avoid for now. I do not have a final state per se. I am only interested in simulating how the state evolves over time based on the state transition table. Is that clearer perhaps?

Comment: Not so much an HMM as a directly observable Markov chain. Which I can't quite see how to avoid here - if (as in your table of allowed transitions) there are states where multiple transitions are valid then we must somehow choose between them. Any method of randomly doing that assigns probabilities, and then we're back to having a state transition matrix with probabilities for each possible transition - illegal transitions having probability 0.

Comment: I posted a new question here which I hope is less confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443709/a-finite-possibly-non-deterministic-state-machine-with-dwell-durations.